# Was Simcity (2013) fixed?

Tags: simcity-2013

There was a lot of bad reviews of [Simcity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FTE2VW), mostly because always-online gaming, small cities... The list is very long.

I never purchased this game because of all the issues that this game haves, and I want to know if it was fixed by EA or someone else.

Edit: For being "fixed", I mean:

1. Bigger cities
2. Offline playing
3. Save and load before disasters

In general the classic features that were removed.

Comment: You're going to be a bit more spesific. The game has had some changes in its lifetime, but we can't really go listing all the things that you _might_ consider "fixes".

Comment: IMHO, if you want a "fixed" SimCity, go get Cities: Skylines

Comment: @DJPirtu you're right, I edited my question mentioned some things that I consider fixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offline playing is now a thing, but your other two issues were not changed.

I've never had a disaster, but the only saving is really on exit.
Bigger cities - I think this is unlikely to change, since they seemed to want to encourage specialization and trading with cities in a region. However, I've been able to fit two specializations in a city.  It depends what you want to have in your city.

Comment: Smaller cities is by design. You need fantastic hardware to run the mod that allows larger ones, if you except it not to crash every five minutes. I never even got it to work.

Comment: Bigger cities, you can just play solo in a whole region and build your smaller cities in the style of a neighborhood/city area